# Add Angular project to already created empty repo

Tags: angular, github, angular-cli

I have Angular CLI and I want to create new project `ng new example` but I have already created a private GitHub repo. How to add a project generated with Angular CLI to repo? just upload?

Comment: If you visit the repo URL, GitHub provides instructions on how to connect an existing local git repo. The fact that it was generated by Angular CLI makes no difference.

Comment: please provie link width this information because I searched and not found. afther this I posted here. thanks

Comment: Literally go to `https://github.com/<username>/<repo>` - while it's empty it shows the instructions. See also https://help.github.com/articles/creating-a-new-repository/ and https://help.github.com/articles/importing-a-git-repository-using-the-command-line/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Should be something like this:

1. Clone the repo that you already have on GitHub. `git clone GITHUB_URL LOCAL_DIR_NAME`
2. `ng new example` and make sure that the content generated land on the project working directory.
3. `git status`
4. `git add .`
5. `git commit -m 'commit message here'`
6. `git push`

Answer (score 6):

If you're looking to generate an existing project into an existing local git-controlled folder, you can use the following option:

```
ng new <ProjectName> --skip-git
```

or simply:

```
ng new <ProjectName> --g
```

In either case, the CLI should still generate a `.gitignore` file in the target directory.

Answer (score 6):

1. First git clone you’re repo so you have it locally.
2. cd (change directory) into your git folder “MyRepo”
3. Execute the following command:

   ng new myapp --directory=./